# R array as.Date conversion

Tags: r

I get an array of dates from a database that I would convert to Date types.

```
> dates
              start            finish
1 29-Oct-2017 00:00 30-Oct-2017 00:00
2 30-Oct-2017 00:00 31-Oct-2017 00:00
3 31-Oct-2017 00:00 01-Nov-2017 00:00
4 01-Nov-2017 00:00 02-Nov-2017 00:00
5 02-Nov-2017 00:00 03-Nov-2017 00:00
6 03-Nov-2017 00:00 04-Nov-2017 00:00
```

I can convert each column *dates['start']* and *dates['finish']* separately with

```
> as.Date(dates['start'][,1], format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")
[1] "2017-10-29" "2017-10-30" "2017-10-31" "2017-11-01" "2017-11-02"
[6] "2017-11-03"
```

But is there a way to do it in one step?

I tried both rows simultaneously, bu that doesn't work.

```
> as.Date(dates[c('start', 'finish')], format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")
Error in as.Date.default(dates[c("start", "finish")], format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M") :
  do not know how to convert 'dates[c("start", "finish")]' to class “Date”
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?as.Date`

> The as.Date methods accept character strings, factors, logical NA and objects of classes "POSIXlt" and "POSIXct".

Assuming that the dataset is `data.frame`, it would not work as the requirements are not met.  We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns, apply the `as.Date` to convert to `Date` class and assign the output back to the columns of interest

```
dates[c('start', 'finish')] <- lapply(dates[c('start', 'finish')], 
         as.Date, format = "%d-%b-%Y %H:%M")
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `mutate_at`

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
dates %>%
      mutate_at(vars(start, finish), dmy_hm)
```